# library deployed on Weblogic server as Prepared

Tags: weblogic, shared-libraries

I have a 2 war projects deployed as a library on a weblogic server (version 1 and version 2) and an EAR project deployed on the same server that uses the library.

When I deploy the library version 2 stays on prepared state and the version 1 remains in active state. Does somebody know how can I do to make active the 2nd version of my war?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Under deployments, did you try selecting the library of interest and explicitly clicking on Activate? If you do not see the library there, you may have to modify the view of your console to include libraries in your deployment page.

If there are conflicts with the other library, you'll get the full stack trace within the stand log files. You also have the option of stopping the currently 'active' library before enabling the newer one to avoid conflicts.